# how to post a form that contains file type parameter using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i'm trying to post an html form using javascript and i can't find how to pass as a parameter the file. If i post the form without using javascript everything works fine. My issue is that i don't know how to pass the file array into a javascript variable. I tried different ways but i can't find the correct one:

```
var fileToUpload1 = $("#fileToUpload2").val();
var fileToUpload1 = document.getElementById("fileToUpload2").files[0];
var fileToUpload1 = document.forms['imageform2']['fileToUpload2'].files[0];
```

I post my code in case it helps. html form and javascript are both in the same file. Upload code is in a seperate file named upload.php.

html form:

```
                <form id="imageform2" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p> Add new photo</p>
                    <p>Description :
                    <textarea id="description2" name= "description2" rows=6 cols=20 required></textarea></p>
                    Category :
                     <select id="category2" name="category">
                        <option value="0">Face</option>
                        <option value="1">Landscape</option>
                        <option value="2">Attraction</option>
                        <option value="3">Object</option>
                    </select>
                    <p>Select image:
                    <input id="fileToUpload2" type="file" name="fileToUpload2" required></p>
                    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                </form>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var description1 = $("#description2").val();
            var category1 = $("#category2").val();
            var fileToUpload1 = $("#fileToUpload2").val();
            alert(description1 + " " + category1 + " " + fileToUpload1);
            if (description1 == '' || category1 == '') 
            {
                if (description1 == '') alert("Insertion Failed description is Blank....!!");
                else if (category1 == '') alert("Insertion Failed category is Blank....!!");
                //else if (fileToUpload1 == '') alert("Insertion Failed fileToUpload is Blank....!!");
                else alert("Insertion Failed Some Fields are Blank....!!");
            } 
            else 
            {
                // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
                $.post("upload.php", 
                {
                    description: description1,
                    category: category1,
                    fileToUpload: fileToUpload1
                }, function(data) {
                alert(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

upload:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
session_start();

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        $_SESSION['uploaded']="true";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is alert(description1 + " " + category1 + " " + fileToUpload1);
giving you? $("#fileToUpload2").val(); <-- gives you C:\[PATH]\ExImg.jpg -- document.getElementById("fileToUpload2").files[0]; <-- gives you an object that you need to get the name field from. So just add '.name' and you'll get the input name. document.getElementById("fileToUpload2").files[0].name will give you Image.filetype without the users path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) to submit a form with AJAX containing file inputs.

First, let's watch for the `onsubmit` event to fire on the form instead of the `onclick` event on the button.

In order to use FormData, we need to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead $.post() because there are settings that need to be added for it to work. FYI $.post() is a shorthand way of using $.ajax() for POST requests. If you need to have more configuration settings, like we do now, use $.ajax().

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imageform2").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // simplified validation logic
        if ($("#description2").val() == '') {
            alert("Insertion Failed description is Blank....!!");
        } else if ($("#category2").val() == '') {
            alert("Insertion Failed category is Blank....!!");
        } else if ($("#fileToUpload2").val() == '') {
            alert("Insertion Failed fileToUpload is Blank....!!");
        } else {
            // send request 
            $.ajax({
                type: this.method,
                url: this.action,
                data: new FormData(this), // important
                processData: false, // important
                contentType: false, // important
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Next on the server-side, let's improve your file checking a little. You should always check the existence of superglobal variable before manipulating it.

Let's wrap the validation logic inside a `try` and `catch`. There's no point in continuing the validation if there is an error at a certain point. We'll quit the validation if an error occurs by throwing an exception with the appropriate message.

```
// just in case, let's turn on the errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $file = isset($_FILES['fileToUpload2']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['fileToUpload2'] : null;
    // start validation
    try {
        // check if file was NOT provided
        if (!$file ||
            !file_exists($file['tmp_name']) || 
            !is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']) || 
            $file['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            throw new Exception('No file was given.');
        }
        // check if file is NOT an image
        $size = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
        if ($size === false) {
            throw new Exception('File is not an image.');
        }
        // check if file already exists
        $target_dir = 'uploads/';
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($file['name']);
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            throw new Exception('File already exists.');
        }
        // check file size is too large
        if ($file['size'] > 2000000) {
            throw new Exception('File is too large.');
        }
        // check file extension is NOT accepted
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (!in_array($extension, ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'])) {
            throw new Exception('Only JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.');
        }
        // if it passes all checks, try uploading file 
        if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
            throw new Exception('There was an error uploading your file.');
        }
        // if we reach this point, then everything worked out!
        echo 'The file ' . basename($file['name']) . ' has been uploaded.';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Of course, the validation could be improved a lot more -- but this is just a quick example.

Comment: It works like a charm thanks you. A small issue with the validation  (it works correct for all my other pictures) but it returns 'No file was given' for a picture named      Hearthstone Screenshot 05-15-16 20.48.12

Comment: That means one of the 4 conditions in the first validation is failing. I would start by looking what value `$file['error']` contains. It will be a number between [0 and 8](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: Thnx for the tip, The problem was that the uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini but i won't change it i guess. Thnx again.